# How to specify GNU / Linux version compiling dropbear

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, dropbear

I have a compiled binary of Dropbear. When I do file dbclient I get the following :

> dbclient: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV),
>   dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

When I am trying to compile it on my own (very beginner) with

> ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/ --disable-zlib
>   CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc LD=arm-linux-gnueabi-ld make make install

I get the following after it compiled

> dbclient: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV),
>   dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31,
>   BuildID[sha1]=0x016ac7e729afb02d60248393619b41380379777d, not stripped

For the stripped part, I don't care I could strip it later.

But my question is how to specify the "**for GNU/Linux 2.6.31**". What does it mean and how do I change it to target **Linux 3.10.49 armv5tejl**?

Comment: linux 2.6.31 is probably the minimum working kernel version for the current file format / ABI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux command "file" shows "for GNU/Linux 2.6.24"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236159/linux-command-file-shows-for-gnu-linux-2-6-24)

Comment: ...or perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133832/what-is-the-version-number-field-in-the-output-of-the-linux-file-command - take your pick.